# How to return selected item on listbox on the second form to the main form in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, forms, listbox

So basically you have a main form that shows only a label (lblTotalPrice) and a button that when you click it, it opens a second form that contains a listbox with different prices packages (lstPackages). How do do you select an item from *lstPackages* that is on the second form and return it to *lblTotalPrice*, which is located on the main form?

I attempted this code using a function (thought it would be useful for calculations), but it seems like it didn't work:

On my second form, I populated the lstPackages with it's name using parallel arrays:

```
Dim strPackages As String = {"Package 1", "Package 2", "Package 3", "Package 4", "Package 5"}
Dim decPrice As String = {100D, 200D, 300D, 400D, 500D}

Private Sub SecondForm_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activate
    Dim frmMain as New 
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To strPackages.Length - 1
       lstPackages.Items.Add(strPackages(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

After I tried to select a value on lstPackages, but I just was not too sure if I was using the right code to select the item and return it to the main form:

```
Function CalcPackage()
    Dim decPackages As Decimal = 0D

    If lstPackages.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Select a package")
    Else
        For i = 0 To lstPackages.SelectedItem - 1
            decPackages = lstPackages.SelectedItem(i)
        Next i
    End If

    Return decPackages
End Function
```

When I have selected the item in the lstPackages, I tried to send the selected item back to the main form, but ran into a problem here:

```
Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Dim frmMainForm As New MainForm
    Dim decTotal As Decimal

    decTotal = CalcPackage()

    'I was stuck in this part and wasn't sure how to return it to lblTotalPrice (and also close the second form too)
    frmMainForm.lblTotalPrice.Text = decTotal.ToString("c")

    frmMainForm.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

So yea sorry if my code is weird, but I'm hoping to get help on how to return the value of the item to lblTotalPrice on the main form, thanks guys

Comment: Forms are objects as the others. Pass a reference to the first form to the second form instance, set the value by calling a method/attribute/field from first form.

Comment: You could create a property on the form called `SelectedPackage` and pass what was selected that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is that you are newing up an instance of the main form in the button exit click event handler of the second form, as shown in this code posted:

```
Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Dim frmMainForm As New MainForm
    Dim decTotal As Decimal

    decTotal = CalcPackage()

    'I was stuck in this part and wasn't sure how to return it to lblTotalPrice (and also close the second form too)
    frmMainForm.lblTotalPrice.Text = decTotal.ToString("c")

    frmMainForm.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Instead pass an instance of the main form to the second form via its constructor, like this:

```
Public Class SecondForm Inherits Form
    Dim theMainForm As MainForm
    Public Sub New(mainForm As MainForm)
        theMainForm = mainForm
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now you can reference the `lblTotalPrice` in the `MainForm` class via the `theMainForm` variable, like this:

```
theMainForm.lblTotalPrice.Text = lstPackages.SelectedItem
```

The `theMainForm.lblTotalPrice.Text` should only be updated in response to an item being selected from `lstPackages` not when the second form is closed; so handle the updating of the main form's label in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `lstPackages`, like this:

```
Protected Sub lstPackages_IndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)        
    Dim decTotal As Decimal
    decTotal = CalcPackage()

    theMainForm.lblTotalPrice.Text = decTotal.ToString("c")
End Sub
```

All the exit button click event handler should do is to show the main form and close the second form, like this:

```
Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    theMainForm.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: But would my function I used to select an item from lstPackages work? And just wondering how would I put this in the btnExit code in order to close the form once you've selected your item?

Comment: Ah this makes more sense now upon separating the calculations and the exit form code, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @PatrickGamboa - no problem, good luck to you and if you have not already then feel free to up-vote the answer. :-)

Comment: This is known as a "tightly coupled" solution since SecondForm must have a reference to frmMainForm.  In this setup, SecondForm cannot work without frmMainForm.  In contrast, see my answer for a "loosely coupled" solution where SecondForm has no knowledge of frmMainForm at all.  SecondForm works independently of frmMainForm, and could even be used with other forms.  Think about the OpenFileDialog(), or the ColorDialog()...would they be as useful if they could only be used with **one specific type** of form?  Anyhoo, neither approach is right or wrong, just different ways to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Just display SecondForm with ShowDialog(), then retrieve the value with the reference to it that you already have:

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sf As New SecondForm
        If sf.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            lblTotalPrice.Text = sf.TotalPrice
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Over in SecondForm:

```
Public Class SecondForm

    Private _TotalPrice As Decimal
    Public ReadOnly Property TotalPrice As Decimal
        Get
            Return _TotalPrice
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        If lstPackages.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Select a package")
        Else
            _TotalPrice = lstPackages.SelectedItem(0)
            Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```